# Track tag not working

Tags: html, html5-video

I am trying to make demo with track tag but track tag is not working from below code my video play only but subtitle is now show on screen

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>track</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video  autoplay="true" controls="" >
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/treeOfLife/video/developerStories-en.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;">
  <track src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/treeOfLife/tracks/developerStories-subtitles-en.vtt" label="English subtitles" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" default=""></track>
</video>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Text tracks are subject to Cross Origin Resource Sharing, which means two things in this case:

1. Your `<video>` element must have the `crossorigin` attribute.
2. The text track source must be served with proper CORS headers.

In this case, the html5rocks site has not enabled any CORS headers for the subtitles, so you won't be able to use them.

Comment: Do you have any demo URL?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure to use .vtt subtitle files. If not there convert using some online tool.

2) Use kind="captions"

3) Run over localhost using xampp...like software

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem recently. You have to make sure that

1. The extension of track file should be .vtt (as told in earlier answers)
2. **Imp.** Make sure that the file is loading into the browser successfully.

To do that, right click and click, inspect element and go to **console** tab.

- Do you see here a message saying "*Unsafe attempt to load URL ...*"? resolve that.
- One of the way of doing that is,

  1. keep the .vtt file in same directory as of index.html
  2. Run the file on some local server. ( you may use any extension, like **live server** for visual studio code.)
  3. This wil enable browser to load both file and security issue will be arised.